# Prove that $F$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(E_n)\geq Km(F)$ under these conditions...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: Suppose $E_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$.  Let $F$ be the set of all points $x\in[0,1]$ that belong to at least $K$ (some positive number) of the $E_n$'s.  Prove that $F$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(E_n)\geq Km(F)$.

**My Attempt/Idea**:  First, let's show that $F$ is measurable.  Let's consider a function $f=\sum_n\chi_{E_n}$.  Then, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is measurable, and so $f^{-1}([K,\infty])$ is measurable.  Since $f^{-1}([K,\infty])$ is precisely the number of points that belong to at least $K$ of the $E_n$'s, we have that $F=f^{-1}([K,\infty])$ is measurable.

Now we want to show the inequality.  $\int f=\int\sum_n\chi_{E_n}=\sum_n\int\chi_{E_n}$, since $f$ are nonnegative functions by MCT.  Let $G$ be the set of all points $x\in[0,1]$ that don't belong to at least $K$ of the $E_n$'s.  Then, $\sum_n\int\chi_{E_n}=\sum_n(\int_F\chi_{E_n}+\int_G\chi_{E_n})$.... but I am not sure if I am on the right track.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Hint: $\int_0^1 f\, dm \ge \int_F f\,dm.$

Comment: So, can I say that $\sum_nm(E_n)=\sum_n\int\chi_{E_n}\geq\sum_n\int_F\chi_{E_n}=Km(F)$..... I suppose we need that $\sum_n\int_G\chi_{E_n}\geq 0$, but that is obvious.  Then, we are done?

Comment: I would just argue $f\ge K$ on $F$ by definition.

Comment: ah, yep, that'll do it.  Just out of curiosity though, there isn't anything I said that is incorrect in my above comment, is there?